# VSE and Compositor

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes

Can you add a strip on the VSE to add a compositing to a strip of video or do you need to compose the part of the video separately?

Comment: You can't compose a movie strip directly. Import a strip or part of it as seqeunce to Compositor and load in VSE as *scene* strip

Comment: Oh ok thanks i was kind of wondering how to use the video editor alongside the compositor as it would be kind of annoying to go back and forward between the two